# Setting up cross-compiler for MIPS-I version 1

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, uclibc

I was looking for cross compiler which is compiling for MIPS-I version 1 target and I found this:

ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/others/sourcecode/toolchains/current-toolchains.tar.bz2

After archive extraction I copied "toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1" folder to /opt/ and added PATH to /root/.profile file like here:

PATH="/opt/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

then I'd log out and log in and thought that everything is all right, but it is not.

I can't even compile simple app. Here is the example output produced by dhcp-3.x compilation attempt:

http://pastebin.com/MPMwirhg

What's wrong ?
Do I still have to set up something ?
How to correct the problem ?

Comment: Essential URL in the body gives 404, making the question useless.

Answer (score 0):

There are hardcoded paths in libraries, so that's why it didn't work. Placing "toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1" folder in /home/xfs/openwrt/trunk2/trunk/staging_dir/ makes it working ok