# Translating uppercase conversion function from C to MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, mips, risc

How can I convert this code to MIPS? I don't understand how each character in an input character pointer can be converted in MIPS.

```
void toUpper(char *s) {
  int n = strlen(s);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      s[i] &= 0xdf;
      }
  }
```

Comment: first hint: ask your compiler what code he will produce

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean..

Comment: @zzzOp Assuming you have a C compiler toolchain, compile the C code and then read the generated machine code from the resulting file. Or ask the compiler to just give you the assembly, many compilers have options to do this.

Comment: compilers do a good job compiling C to ASM, esp with optimization turned on. so whenever you have no idea what to do, compile the C code with a (cross) compiler, and see what code it produces. Just in case you don't have a C-Compiler for MIPS: I searched a bit, and found this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006843/compile-c-for-mips-architecture]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a C compiler toolchain. (Edit: nevermind, the link provide is great! Thanks @Tommylee2k

Comment: Even if you were to do this manually I don't really see what the question is. Basic knowledge of MIPS assembly language programming would be a prerequisite for a task like this. If you don't feel that you have that - find yourself a book or tutorial on the subject and start learning. If you do know MIPS assembly you would have to clarify exactly what you're having trouble with because this seems pretty straightforward (just a couple of loops with some loads/stores and an AND-operation).

Comment: I have found this SO post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175450/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcc-to-convert-c-to-mips) .

Comment: that isn't even a valid `toUpper()` function.  It'll only work reliably on 7-bit ASCII alphabetical characters and will change many other characters in unexpected ways.

Comment: it's inefficient too - scanning the string twice!

Comment: May I kindly what's the point of discouraging the OP to the point of rather not asking a question without prerequisite knowledge which would render asking pointless? It's a good point that code intended to be written in assembly language should be efficient. This algorithm is ASCII-character only indeed, and the reading procedure is inefficient, but does it disqualify? Thanks.

Comment: no, what disqualifies is that he didn't try himself, and just threw in his C-Code, instead of at least starting to develop. SO is no coding service

Comment: @user3078414: I'm not trying to discourage people from asking good questions. But a code dump along with _"How do I translate this from language X to language Y?"_ doesn't qualify as a good question in my book. Plus, if the question could be answered with just a basic understanding of X and Y (at least based on the information the OP has provided) then I have to question the OP's research effort.

Comment: @Tommylee2k, thanks - it wasn't my faintest idea to challenge your or anyone's opinion about SO not being a coding service, because it's clear *it is not* and it shouldn't be. Yet, whenever put into position of possibly being judgmental, I prefer keeping "on the softer side", or at least asking one extra question...